# How to implement contrast adjustment over a gradient in python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for a way to adjust an images brightness and contrast over a gradient. The upper left corner has good quality and it drops towards the bottom right corner. I've been trying with opencv in python.

Is there a way to use for instance opencv's `cv2.convertScaleAbs`, but the pixel transformation is dependent on the gradient image? Using only `cv2.convertScaleAbs` does improve the image, but the difference in lightning stays visible.

I hope someone here can put me on the right track :)

Thanks!

The image:

[image]

The desired result looks somewhat like this:
[image]

The gradient I've been trying to use:

[image]

Comment: Minimize gradient image, and use as filter to input image

Comment: Thanks for commenting @NawinKSharma :) , how would I do this?